# How to express an unicode code points set in match command?

Tags: unicode, matchlist

My test.txt for this example.

```
　  unicode 3000  (whitespace in Chinese mark)
！  unicode ff01
＾  unicode ff3e
～  unicode ff5e
```

[image]

The command can match  whitespace in Chinese mark(`u3000`).

```
hi! ChineseMark ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ChineseMark /\%u3000/
```

[image]

And `！` can be matched with

```
match ChineseMark /\%uff01/
```

[image]

And `＾` can be matched with

```
match ChineseMark /\%uff3e/
```

And `！` can be matched with

```
match ChineseMark /\%uff5e/
```

Now i want to match character whose unicode code point is `u3000` and characters whose unicode code points are from `uff01` till `uff5e`.

```
match ChineseMark /[\%u3000\%uff01-\$uff5e]/
```

The expression `/[\%u3000\%uff01-\$uff5e]/` can't do the trick,How to express this kind of unicode code points  set in match command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for unicode characters inside `[]` is different, you just omit the `%`:

```
match ChineseMark /[\u3000\uff01-\uff5e]/
```

`\%uxxxx` is an atom while `\uff01` is character in a collection.  You cannot use atoms inside collections.  See `:help /[`.